# Write data to textbox row by row from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, datareader

i want to display data from database row by row in table

[image]

how to write data from database to each textbox row wise

(i.e) date activity1,activity2 etc then next row date activity1,activyt2 etc..
how to write proper loop

The code i have tried for getting data for first row:

```
private void GetActivity()
    {
        try
        {
            CON = new OracleConnection(Connection);
            CON.Open();
            OracleCommand COMMAND1 = new OracleCommand("Select ACTIVITYID,to_char(ACTIVITYDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') as ACTIVITYDATE,TITLE,STARTTIME,ENDTIME,ACTIVITYTIME as TIMETAKEN from DAILY_ACTIVITIES1 where ACTIVITYDATE= (Select min(ACTIVITYDATE) from DAILY_ACTIVITIES1)", CON);

            OracleDataReader READER = COMMAND1.ExecuteReader();            
            int count = READER.FieldCount;

            if (READER.HasRows)
            {
                while (READER.Read())
                {
                    if (Date1TextBox.Text == "")
                    {
                        Date1TextBox.Text = READER[1].ToString();
                        Date1TextBox.Enabled = false;
                    }

                    if (D1A1TextBox.Text == "")
                    {
                        D1A1TextBox.Text = "Title:" + READER[2].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A1TextBox.Text += "Start-time:" + READER[3].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A1TextBox.Text += "End-time:" + READER[4].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A1TextBox.Text += "Timetaken:" + READER[5].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A1TextBox.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        D1A1TextBox.Enabled = false;
                    }

                    if (D1A2TextBox.Text == "")
                    {
                        D1A2TextBox.Text = "Title:" + READER[2].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A2TextBox.Text += "Start-time:" + READER[3].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A2TextBox.Text += "End-time:" + READER[4].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A2TextBox.Text += "Timetaken:" + READER[5].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A2TextBox.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        D1A2TextBox.Enabled = false;
                    }

                    if (D1A3TextBox.Text == "")
                    {
                        D1A3TextBox.Text = "Title:" + READER[2].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A3TextBox.Text += "Start-time:" + READER[3].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A3TextBox.Text += "End-time:" + READER[4].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A3TextBox.Text += "Timetaken:" + READER[5].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A3TextBox.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        D1A3TextBox.Enabled = false;
                    }

                    if (D1A4TextBox.Text == "")
                    {
                        D1A4TextBox.Text = "Title:" + READER[2].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A4TextBox.Text += "Start-time:" + READER[3].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A4TextBox.Text += "End-time:" + READER[4].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A4TextBox.Text += "Timetaken:" + READER[5].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A4TextBox.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        D1A4TextBox.Enabled = false;
                    }

                    if (D1A5TextBox.Text == "")
                    {
                        D1A5TextBox.Text = "Title:" + READER[2].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A5TextBox.Text += "Start-time:" + READER[3].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A5TextBox.Text += "End-time:" + READER[4].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A5TextBox.Text += "Timetaken:" + READER[5].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A5TextBox.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        D1A5TextBox.Enabled = false;
                    }

                    if (D1A6TextBox.Text == "")
                    {
                        D1A6TextBox.Text = "Title:" + READER[2].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A6TextBox.Text += "Start-time:" + READER[3].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A6TextBox.Text += "End-time:" + READER[4].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A6TextBox.Text += "Timetaken:" + READER[5].ToString() + "\n";
                        D1A6TextBox.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        D1A6TextBox.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }          
            CON.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception et)
        {
            et.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: kumartyr , where you get D1A1TextBox~D1A6TextBox?

Comment: @AngusChung Those are all textboxes which are placed in first row of the table with multiline = true (i.e) highlighted one is D1A3textbox

Comment: i know but how can you use they in GetActivity() directly?

Comment: I am calling this method in Pageload of my webform

Comment: ok,   i understood your question , you want a loop to do it?

Comment: may i ask a question ?  why not use Gridview to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75262/discussion-between-kumartyr-and-angus-chung).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@kumartyr , according to your needs , you don't want to use Gridview.

So , i rewrite the GetActivity() funtion for **dynamic Textbox** access.

```
private void GetActivity()
{
    try
    {
        CON = new OracleConnection(Connection);
        CON.Open();
        OracleCommand COMMAND1 = new OracleCommand("Select ACTIVITYID,to_char(ACTIVITYDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') as ACTIVITYDATE,TITLE,STARTTIME,ENDTIME,ACTIVITYTIME as TIMETAKEN from DAILY_ACTIVITIES1 where ACTIVITYDATE= (Select min(ACTIVITYDATE) from DAILY_ACTIVITIES1)", CON);

        OracleDataReader READER = COMMAND1.ExecuteReader();
        int count = READER.FieldCount;

        if (READER.HasRows)
        {
            int i = 1;
            TextBox txtDate;
            TextBox txtDA;
            ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("MainContent");
            while (READER.Read() && i <= 6)
            {
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    txtDate = (TextBox)cph.FindControl(string.Format("Date{0}TextBox", i.ToString()));
                    txtDate.Text = READER[1].ToString();
                    txtDate.Enabled = false;
                }

                txtDA = (TextBox)cph.FindControl(string.Format("D1A{0}TextBox", i.ToString()));
                if (txtDA.Text == "")
                {
                    txtDA.Text = "Title:" + READER[2].ToString() + "\n";
                    txtDA.Text += "Start-time:" + READER[3].ToString() + "\n";
                    txtDA.Text += "End-time:" + READER[4].ToString() + "\n";
                    txtDA.Text += "Timetaken:" + READER[5].ToString() + "\n";
                }
                txtDA.Enabled = false;
                i++;
            }
        }
        CON.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception et)
    {
        et.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a GridView and bind your OracleCommand as the DataSource. You can customize each cell to show the data you want and you don't have to do any looping or manually add thousands of textboxes.

Here's the documentation with tons of examples:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [GridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx)?, you can create row template and bind the grid view all at once in RowDataBound event

these are easy way to bind gridview. [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23471/Editable-GridView-in-ASP-NET) is a very good example